# How do I change my user profile picture?

Tags: greeter, user, profile

Currently my user profile picture is a small circular person:

[image]

How do I change this?

Comment: Why is it that there are no default Elementary native profile pictures to choose in the first place?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Open system settings and click User Accounts.

[image]

Click your current profile picture, and chose "Select From File":

[image]

Then navigate to the file, and click Open

[image]

Chose the section with the box, and then click "Change Avatar".

[image]

Your chosen image will be set as your profile picture:

[image]