# How can I change the guest session profile picture

Tags: user, profile

I know I can enable and disable it but once enabled, the guest session has this white/blue user profile picture. I would like to change this image, is it currently possible ? Any way to do it manually ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change my user profile picture?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/24/how-do-i-change-my-user-profile-picture)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need a combination of

- [How do I change my user profile picture?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/24/how-do-i-change-my-user-profile-picture?rq=1) and
- [How can I have the same applications in the Dock for the Guest session as I have in the Administrator account?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9069/how-can-i-have-the-same-applications-in-the-dock-for-the-guest-session-as-i-have?rq=1)